# SVG + transform-origin problems in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, weather

I'm building a weather component using the SVGs from this link: http://codepen.io/TechnotronicOz/pen/eokCA
(Here's an example of one of the icons)

```
    <svg
    version="1.1"
    id="sun"
    class="climacon climacon_sun"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="15 15 70 70"
    enable-background="new 15 15 70 70"
    xml:space="preserve">
    <clipPath id="sunFillClip">
        <path
        d="M0,0v100h100V0H0z M50.001,57.999c-4.417,0-8-3.582-8-7.999c0-4.418,3.582-7.999,8-7.999s7.998,3.581,7.998,7.999C57.999,54.417,54.418,57.999,50.001,57.999z"
        />
    </clipPath>
    <g class="climacon_iconWrap climacon_iconWrap-sun">
        <g class="climacon_componentWrap climacon_componentWrap-sun">
            <g class="climacon_componentWrap climacon_componentWrap-sunSpoke">
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-east"
                d="M72.03,51.999h-3.998c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-1.999s0.895-2,2-2h3.998c1.104,0,2,0.896,2,2S73.136,51.999,72.03,51.999z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-northEast"
                d="M64.175,38.688c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828l2.828-2.828c0.779-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.828,0c0.779,0.781,0.779,2.047,0,2.828L64.175,38.688z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-north"
                d="M50.034,34.002c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-2v-3.999c0-1.104,0.895-2,2-2c1.104,0,2,0.896,2,2v3.999C52.034,33.106,51.136,34.002,50.034,34.002z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-northWest"
                d="M35.893,38.688l-2.827-2.828c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828c0.78-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.827,0l2.827,2.828c0.781,0.781,0.781,2.047,0,2.828C37.94,39.469,36.674,39.469,35.893,38.688z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-west"
                d="M34.034,50c0,1.104-0.896,1.999-2,1.999h-4c-1.104,0-1.998-0.896-1.998-1.999s0.896-2,1.998-2h4C33.14,48,34.034,48.896,34.034,50z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-southWest"
                d="M35.893,61.312c0.781-0.78,2.048-0.78,2.827,0c0.781,0.78,0.781,2.047,0,2.828l-2.827,2.827c-0.78,0.781-2.047,0.781-2.827,0c-0.781-0.78-0.781-2.047,0-2.827L35.893,61.312z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-south"
                d="M50.034,65.998c1.104,0,2,0.895,2,1.999v4c0,1.104-0.896,2-2,2c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-2v-4C48.034,66.893,48.929,65.998,50.034,65.998z"
                />
                <path
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke climacon_component-stroke_sunSpoke-southEast"
                d="M64.175,61.312l2.828,2.828c0.779,0.78,0.779,2.047,0,2.827c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0l-2.828-2.827c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.048,0-2.828C62.126,60.531,63.392,60.531,64.175,61.312z"
                />
            </g>
            <g class="climacon_componentWrap climacon_componentWrap_sunBody" clip-path="url(#sunFillClip)">
                <circle
                class="climacon_component climacon_component-stroke climacon_component-stroke_sunBody"
                cx="50.034"
                cy="50"
                r="11.999"
                />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg><!-- sun
```

Works beautifully in chrome. I just spent a while trying to debug firefox until I realized that even his example is messed up in that browser. I don't know much about SVGs so if anyone has some tips that would be great. I'm starting to lean towards picking a different set of weather icons. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: What does "incorrectly" mean. The icon looks like a sun when I view it. Isn't that what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: This has to do with Firefox handling the transform origin differently than Chrome, I believe. It's a browser bug, so there's nothing you can do on your end to fix it, other than use a different approach.

Comment: Looks ok to me in FF 41.0.1

Comment: @TylerH The code included in the question does not contain transform-origin.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry, I'm not referring to the `transform-origin` property (though they're somewhat related), I'm referring to how the browser handles origin points; e.g. spinning around the wrong origin, setting origin to the wrong element, etc. There are multiple outstanding bugs related to that matter in Bugzilla.

Comment: @RobertLongson if you check the link I provided in FF it should show the sun and other shapes rotating in and out of view, while on Chrome it sits in one spot and the rays rotate around it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapes expect the transform-box property to be fill-box i.e.

```
transform-box: fill-box
```

Firefox only supports this if the about:config svg.transform-origin.enabled is set to true (Firefox 41, 42) or svg.transform-box.enabled is set to true (Firefox 43 onwards).

Chrome is wrong here as it is assuming that the origin is the fill-box rather than the view-box as the [specification states](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box). This inconsistency with the specification is why it's not enabled in Firefox by default as the specification may change to match Chrome's implementation.